# cut -c equivalent in Windows

Tags: android, bash

I am trying to run logs using Android studio. My company uses Macs, but I have a PC. There is one command we use to run these logs, and I am trying to find the Windows version of the command.

The code is:

> adb logcat | grep 'adb shell ps | grep com.company.company | cut -c10-15' >> /Users/all/Desktop/android.log

I already know `grep` should be changed to `findstr`, However, I can not find the windows equivalent to the `cut` command.

I am also not 100% sure what `shell` or `ps` are either.

Comment: You can use the original tools also on windows. Most GNU tools are available as exe for Windows. A very simple installer for such tools is [Scoop](http://scoop.sh/) (lightweight package manager). cut is e.g. available via scoop `coreutils` package.

Answer (score 0):

To have a powerful scripting environment in Windows you can use [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/getting-started-with-windows-powershell?view=powershell-5.1).
with PowerShell you can you can open a file and split lines with a script like:

```
$filename = "myfile.txt"

Get-Content $filename | ForEach-Object {
    $_.split(" ")[1]
}
```

Get-Content is alternative to cat and split() is alternative to cat. 
Get-Content's output is piped to forEach-Object loop!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer shows the equivalent of
cut -d" " -f2
(to return second field -first being [0]-, using the space as a separator)
which is not what has been asked for:
cut -c10-15
(to return characters from the 10th to 15th, both included)